# reStructuredText long section title

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Is there any way to linewrap a long section title in reStructuredText?

My Linter keeps complaining about exceeding the maximum line length, which drives me crazy.

The section title in question includes `:any:` references, that can by nature not be reworded to be shorter.

I have searched RST tutorials left and right, but found no syntax whatsoever for this.

RST interpreter in question is Sphinx v1.8.5 on Python 3.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to linewrap a section title in RestructuredText.

However you can probably use [RestructuredText Substitutions](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions) to accomplish what you want.

e.g.

```
====================================
This is a |subst| long section title
====================================

.. |subst| replace:: (Insert this very long text,
                     which can even be line-wrapped)
```